# Android Send Email (w/ Username and Password authentication) with android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am trying to send an email to a specific address by using my own email.
So far, I know that I can use `android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND` to send an email. For istance:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new
Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
    new String[]{"blabla@gmail.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
    "Log-in Sucessful");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi");

Activity context = null;
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

However, I do not know whether `ACTION_SEND` can accept username and password as well. This username and password basically will be used to authenticate the email sender. It's just like when you need to log-in into your gmail account before you can compose and send an email to someone.

Do you guys by any chance know any solution/guide to do this?

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 2):

CommonsWare got to it before me but what he/she said. :D

Basically ACTION_SEND is simply a 'generic' send intent(ion) and that's the point of the chooser. Example...if I pick a contact on my phone to send email to, I get a choice of using a 'Mail' app (SMTP/POP3/IMAP4) or the GMail app. In either case, I've configured these apps with username/password details and where necessary, the incoming/outgoing server details needed.

In short, username/password are useless as ACTION_SEND doesn't explicitly know which outgoing server those details apply to.

From what I can tell, you want to automate this entirely which suggests you need to create your own SMTP client code which you can pass username/password and server details along with the message.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I do not know whether ACTION_SEND can accept username and password as well.

No, it does not, nor should it. The email client must have an email account configured.